# Html css drag and dop file uploading style

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, file

I am making a html css and javascript drag and drop file uploading system. I also style the file button. But, a little of file button background is show in the top left. I want to remove it. But, I can't. There is also another problem. When I drag a picture on the 'cloud icon' or

Check in the [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/sultanul9/Lw17t72z/)

And See the screenshot please:

[image: Html css drag and dop file uploading style]

Here is My all code.
**HTML**

```
<form id="form1"> 
 <label for="imgInp" class="custom-file-upload"> 
      <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>Chosse file</label>
       <input type='file' id="imgInp" /></div>        
</form>
 <img id="blah" src="">
```

**CSS**

```
input[type='file'] {
    border: 3px dashed #999;
    cursor: move;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0px;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    min-height: 160px;
    min-width: 300px;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: right;
    top: 0;
    background: transparent;
    z-index:-99999999999999;
} 
img#blah {
    display: block;
}


.custom-file-upload {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 83px;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 9999;
    width:75px;
    margin-left:-50.5px;
}

#form1 div {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    height: 170px;
}

input[type='file']:before {
    content: "Upload an Image";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: -25px 0 0 -100px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #999;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function readURL(input) {
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

Comment: Hide your input using display none and add all your style on the label.

Comment: Hi, @RajanBenipuri I am tried like you said. But, drag and drop is not woriking.

Comment: You will have to use some js for drag and drop to work

Comment: Oh. I haven't any idea about this. Could please suggest me about this code? And send me the JS code.

Comment: I wish I could but I am really sorry I am using SO on my mobile right now and its very painful to write codes on mobile. Hope someone else will give you the desired answer and if not I will definitely help you out tomorrow

Comment: Sure. I am waiting for your response.

Answer (score 1):

check this i made `display:none` for the file input  and made the image click  call file input with jquery and also changed every reference of the file input to the image like `input[type=file]` to `input[type=image]`

```js
function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }
            
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
    $("input[type='image']").click(function() {
    $("input[id='imgInp']").click();
});
    $("#imgInp").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
```

```css
input[type='image'] {
    border: 3px dashed #999;
    cursor: move;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0px;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    min-height: 160px;
    min-width: 300px;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: right;
    top: 0;
    background: transparent;
    z-index:-99999999999999;
} 
img#blah {
    display: block;
}
       

.custom-file-upload {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 83px;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 9999;
    width:75px;
    margin-left:-50.5px;
}

#form1 div {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    height: 170px;
}

input[type='image']:before {
    content: "Upload an Image";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: -25px 0 0 -100px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1">
   <div>
   
 <label for="imgInp" class="custom-file-upload">  <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>Chosse file</label>
 <input type="image" id="blah">
 <input type='file' id="imgInp" style="display:none;"/></div>  
        
    </form>
```

Comment: It's great. But, I need also drag and drop system. The uploaded image should be show under the file uploader.